# Let $p(x)$ have a zero $a\in \mathbb{Q}$ ...

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

"Let $p(x)$ have a zero $a\in \mathbb{Q}$..."

Where $p(x)$ is a polynomial.

I came about this part of a statement and I was not entirely sure what it meant. Although, I assumed that it meant that there exists an element $a\in \mathbb{Q}$ such that if I substitute it into the polynomial $p(x)$ it would give $zero$. But I'm not entirely sure.

If someone can clarify this for me, I would appreciate it. Thanks

Comment: Your understanding is correct.

Comment: As the above comment said, that's it really. Is there still something you're unsure of?

Comment: @Servaes , thanks. Now I fully understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you are entirely correct. It means that there is some $a\in \mathbb Q$ such that $p(a) = 0$.

But you can also think of it this way: $(x - a)$ divides $p(x)$. That is $$p(x) = (x-a)q(x)$$ where $q(x)$ whose degree is one less than the degree of $p(x)$.

Comment: It would be helpful to add that $q(x)$ would be a polynomial of degree $\deg(p)-1$.

Answer (score 2):

You're correct. That sentence, in English, means that there exists a rational number such that the polynomial evaluated at that rational number yields $0$.